# How is the waittime calculated in printer simulation python program?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am currently learning datastructures and algorithms.
I found this code on [Interactive python](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/SimulationPrintingTasks.html)

```
from pythonds.basic.queue import Queue

import random

class Printer:
    def __init__(self, ppm):
        self.pagerate = ppm
        self.currentTask = None
        self.timeRemaining = 0

    def tick(self):
        if self.currentTask != None:
            self.timeRemaining = self.timeRemaining - 1
            if self.timeRemaining <= 0:
                self.currentTask = None

    def busy(self):
        if self.currentTask != None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def startNext(self,newtask):
        self.currentTask = newtask
        self.timeRemaining = newtask.getPages() * 60/self.pagerate

class Task:
    def __init__(self,time):
        self.timestamp = time
        self.pages = random.randrange(1,21)

    def getStamp(self):
        return self.timestamp

    def getPages(self):
        return self.pages

    def waitTime(self, currenttime):
        return currenttime - self.timestamp


def simulation(numSeconds, pagesPerMinute):

    labprinter = Printer(pagesPerMinute)
    printQueue = Queue()
    waitingtimes = []

    for currentSecond in range(numSeconds):

      if newPrintTask():
         task = Task(currentSecond)
         printQueue.enqueue(task)

      if (not labprinter.busy()) and (not printQueue.isEmpty()):
        nexttask = printQueue.dequeue()
        waitingtimes.append( nexttask.waitTime(currentSecond))
        labprinter.startNext(nexttask)

      labprinter.tick()

    averageWait=sum(waitingtimes)/len(waitingtimes)
    print("Average Wait %6.2f secs %3d tasks remaining."%(averageWait,printQueue.size()))

def newPrintTask():
    num = random.randrange(1,181)
    if num == 180:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for i in range(10):
    simulation(3600,5)
```

Please can someone explain how does the waitingtimes.append( nexttask.waitTime(currentSecond)) compute waitime for the currentsecond.
Won't it be zero for that particular currentsecond.
Also as per the simulation, every 180 seconds there is a newtask , but it is enqueued and dequeued in the same currentsecond.
So the printqueue is always empty at any particular time or is it ?

Please Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every second, there is a random chance a task is added to the *queue*. Only if the printer is *available* (`not labprinter.busy()` is true) is then a task taken from the queue to be sent to the printer.

Once a task is been added to the printer, it'll take that printer a a certain number of ticks ('seconds') to handle the random number of pages assigned to each task. No new task can then be sent to it! Each loop iteration `labprinter.tick()` is called, which decrements `self.timeRemaining` (calculated based on the task size and printer page rate). Only when that number reaches 0 is the task cleared and is the printer no longer busy (ready to take another task).

So the queue could be filling up while the printer is busy. Tasks that spend several rounds of the loop in the queue will have had a waiting time accumulate.

You could write down the ticks; lets say it can handle 20 pages per minute, so it'll take 3 seconds per page:

- 0. Nothing happens
- 1. A task of size 10 is created. The printer is free, so it'll take the task. 10 pages take 30 seconds.
- 2 - 5. No new tasks are created, the printer prints 1 page.
- 6 - 9. One new task is created at tick 8, added to the queue. The printer prints a 2nd page.
- 9 - 30. More tasks could be created, the printer prints the rest of the pages.
- 31. The printer is free, the task created at tick 8 can now be handled. That task waited 31 - 8 == 23 seconds.

Comment: Thanks that was a clear cut explanation...thanks a lot!!